# Error when converting csv stock data to xts

Tags: r, xts, zoo

Below is the code I am trying to use to convert the csv file to xts so that I can perform analysis to it but nothing seems to work. I have even used answers for similar issue that have been posted on this platform but nothing seems to be working.

```
toDate <- function(x) as.Date(x, origin = "2015-02-15")
z <- read.zoo("Nasdaq.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", FUN = toDate)
x <- as.xts(z)
```

I get below error:

```
7. stop("character string is not in a standard unambiguous format") 
6. charToDate(x) 
5. as.Date.character(x, origin = "2015-02-15") 
4. as.Date(x, origin = "2015-02-15") 
3. FUN(...) 
2. processFUN(ix) 
1. read.zoo("Nasdaq.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", FUN = toDate)
```

Comment: If you post the output of dput(z), others will be able to replicate your issue, which would help in answering the question.

Comment: The error message seems clear -- the dates in your file are not in standard form.  You will need to supply a format so it knows how to interpret them.  Without a reproducible example (the input csv file is missing) can't say much more.  Please review [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Problem is when you reading file as zoo. 
If is a time series, try load file, than turn it into ts.

```
data <-  read.csv("anyfile.csv")
Y <- ts(data$Y, start = c(2015, 2), end = c(2017, 1), frequency = 12)
my_xts <- as.xts(Y)
```

Comment: I have tried that but am still getting errors like: Error in as.xts(Y) : object 'Y' not found

Comment: If you could share at least a piece of your data. 10 lines will work for testing.

Comment: or add 
`as.Date(x, format, tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d"))` to your first line